# How to make scrapy output info show the same cjk appearance in debian as in windows?

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy, locale

```
import scrapy
from info.items import InfoItem

class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'info'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.money.163.com']
    start_urls = [ r"http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = StockinfoItem()
        item["content"] = response.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/table/tr[2]/td[2]").extract()[0]
        yield item
```

For the above spider, execute on my windows (win7) english version,the scrapy info shows:

```
2019-04-27 23:27:41 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: info)
2019-04-27 23:27:41 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
2019-04-27 23:27:41 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'info', 'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['content'], 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'info.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['info.spiders']}
2019-04-27 23:27:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html> (referer: None)
2019-04-27 23:27:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html>
{'content': ['浙能电力']}
```

Now execute on my linux os(debian 9),the scrapy info shows:

```
2019-04-28 07:12:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: info)
2019-04-28 07:12:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 16.6.0, Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) - [GCC 6.3.0 20170516], pyOpenSSL 16.2.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 1.7.1, Platform Linux-4.9.0-8-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-9.8
2019-04-28 07:12:00 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'info.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['info.spiders'], 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8', 'BOT_NAME': 'info'}
2019-04-28 07:12:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html> (referer: None)
2019-04-28 07:12:01 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html>
{'content': u'\u6d59\u80fd\u7535\u529b'}
```

The locale info in my debian 9.

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How can i make scrapy output info show the same (in same cjk appearance)in my debian as in my windows?

There are two python version in my debian.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip
```

My scrapy1.6 was build on python2.7,maybe to reinstall scrapy on python3 can solve the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using Python 3 in Windows and Python 2 in Debian?

Comment: No, python3 in debian too.

Comment: Can You share us with more detailed version information? I mean part of scrapy log output (especially log lines starting with `[scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: ....`) for both Windows and Debian environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool stack info on my debian shows that

```
2019-04-28 07:12:00 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 16.6.0, Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22)
```

THere are two python version in my debian:python2.7 and python3.5,scrapy was installed in python2.7,uninstall scrapy in python2.7 and reinstall it in python3.5.

```
sudo pip uninstall Scrapy
sudo pip3 install Scrapy
```

To run the spider ,it shows same cjk appearance in debian as in win7 now.